# export installed eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, export, pmd

I would like to know if it is possible to export an installed eclipse plugin with my proper preference configuration.

In fact, I've developed a fragment project for the pmd plugin and I've linked it with the installed plugin by configuring the pmd preference. And now I want to export it as a new eclipse plugin instance.

Thanks for your help ;)

Cheng

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean exporting your preferences?  That can be done using *File>Export...>General>Preferences*.  But preferences are (usually) stored in the workspace, and the plugin (which is part of the install) stores and uses them.

Exporting a fragment can be done from *File>Export...>Plug-in Development>Deployable plug-in and fragment*.

If this is not what you want, please clarify.

Comment: Actually, I need to export an existing plugin which is configured in eclipse preference(in other words, I've added some rules if you do know the [pmd plugin](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/integrations.html#eclipse)) for installing the same plugin on another eclipse instance. The fragment project is used as a patch to the plugin.

Comment: A plugin is installable.  If you have configured something in the preferences, you need to export preferences (probably not the plugin).   If you export all of your preferences, can you see any of your PMD related stuff?

Comment: Yep, I see there are sth about pmd in the .epf file. But I should better find a way to export only those added rules in the pmd plugin, not all the eclipse preferences. Perhaps the proper way is to install the plugin and copy the fragment jar then import all the rules via pmd plugin. Yet it's not that convenient...

Comment: The only way to restrict preferences is if the plugin provides a "preference transfer", like we do for _CVS Repositories_.